# Is $f(x,y)=\frac{3x^2-5y^2\sin(x)}{|x|+|y|}$ continous at $(0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{3x^2-5y^2\sin(x)}{|x|+|y|} & \text{ if }\, (x,y)\neq (0,0),\\ 0 & \text{ if }\, (x,y)=(0,0).\end{cases}$$ continous at $(0,0)$?

When I want to check if $f(x,y)$ is continous at $(0,0)$, I basically have to look at the limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{3x^2-5y^2\sin(x)}{|x|+|y|}$$

If we approach $(0,0)$ along the axes we have the following:

$x$-axis:
$$\lim_{(0,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{3\cdot 0^2-5y^2\sin(0)}{|0|+|y|} = 0$$

$y$-axis:
$$\lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)} \frac{3 x^2-5\cdot0^2\sin(x)}{|x|+|0|} = 0$$

But how do I go for the general case?

Answer (score 2):

$\frac {3x^{2}} {|x|+|y|}\leq \frac {3x^{2}} {|x|}=3|x| \to 0$ and $\frac {|5y^{2}\sin x|} {|x|+|y|} \le \frac {5y^{2}} {|y|} =5|y| \to 0$. So $f(x,y) \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. $f$ is not defined at $(0,0)$ but it becomes continuous if you define $f(0,0)$ as $0$.